# Sequelize reset table to old version in express application

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm working on a express project with sequelize, all works fine, just from time to time happen something strange and annoying:

I've created a table, initially the table was:

```
{sonId, birthDate: date, userId }
```

after a while I've decided to modify the table:

```
 {sonId, ageRange: string, userId }
```

All works fine but sometimes happen that the row ageRange became the old birthDate, without any clear reason.

To fix the error I need to restart my express app, after the restart the table became newly ageRange but the value comes to null.

Why is that possibile? I've not used migration, I'm working on the first structure for now, I've not used the sequelize cli... seems that there is some cached db version..

Anyone con help me to find out whats happen?

Answer (score 0):

Storage account speed limit is `25Gbps` while Blob speed limit is `60Mb/s`.
The low speed you have may be because:

1. You're using other services that consume speed and you're right at the limit (small posibility)
2. Because of the network latency those `60Mbps` become `20Mbps`. There is already a small limit (60) that can be affected by anything significantly.